# How to minimize axios posts with controller actions

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am creating an application with Laravel and VueJs. In this application a user can create an event. These events have participants. In my application the user fills out all of the event information and participants information and then clicks submit.

What I am looking for guidance on is how to best structure this in the backend. What I need to accomplish is the following:

- create an event to the database
- create participants
- do an action based on the participants in the event (would happen in the event controller)

right now the way I have structured this is:

- Send an axios post to create the event (EventController)
- then send an axios post to create participants (ParticipantController)
- then send another axios post to the event controller to do the last action (EventController)

this to me feels like way too many axios post calls, but I don't want to just put everything in one controller. Is there a better way to do what I am wanting to do while minimizing the number of axios calls?

Comment: Can you show us the logic you already have in your Controllers? I think you can send all data to EventController and handle participants logic on a Service, but it's hard to say without more info

Answer (score 0):

if you need to create participants and perform particular action after event create then you can use laravel observers you can use it's created function to perform any action like after createing an event you have to make some enteries on participant table so you can perform those actions in that observer function.